How to communicate a postgres db and Django container inside ECS?
I need some guidance with this pipeline to deploy a test to ECS, i know that a postgres db in a container is not the best solutions compared to RDS and others but i would like at least to know if it is possible hehe. Im stuck with this for days, it just get stuck in part of running wait-for-it.sh file and does not connect to db, i checked in AWS cloudwatch and the db is getting ready to accept connections, but Django never connects to it. Im using a default VPC attached to the ECS cluster and have inside it a security group with inbound rules to allow traffic in port 8000 for ay IP and other for 5432 port that allows traffic to any IP too, what is wrong?
name: CD Pipeline

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - main

jobs:
  deploy-ecs:
    name: Deploy to ECS
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
      - name: Checkout code
        uses: actions/checkout@v2

      - name: Set up Docker Buildx
        uses: docker/setup-buildx-action@v1

      - name: Configure AWS credentials
        uses: aws-actions/configure-aws-credentials@v1
        with:
          aws-access-key-id: ${{ secrets.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID }}
          aws-secret-access-key: ${{ secrets.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY }}
          aws-region: ${{ secrets.AWS_REGION }}

      - name: Log in to Amazon ECR
        uses: aws-actions/amazon-ecr-login@v1

      
      - name: Check if backend Docker image exists
        id: backend-image-check
        run: |
          IMAGE_TAG=${{ secrets.AWS_ACCOUNT_ID }}.dkr.ecr.${{ secrets.AWS_REGION }}.amazonaws.com/backend:latest
          if aws ecr describe-images --repository-name backend --image-ids imageTag=latest; then
            echo "Backend image exists."
            echo "::set-output name=exists::true"
          else
            echo "Backend image does not exist."
            echo "::set-output name=exists::false"
          fi


      - name: Build and push backend Docker image
        if: steps.backend-image-check.outputs.exists == 'false'
        run: |
          docker buildx build --platform linux/amd64,linux/arm64 -f ./backend/DockerfileProd -t ${{ secrets.AWS_ACCOUNT_ID }}.dkr.ecr.${{ secrets.AWS_REGION }}.amazonaws.com/backend:latest --push ./backend

      - name: Check if frontend Docker image exists
        id: frontend-image-check
        run: |
          IMAGE_TAG=${{ secrets.AWS_ACCOUNT_ID }}.dkr.ecr.${{ secrets.AWS_REGION }}.amazonaws.com/frontend:latest
          if aws ecr describe-images --repository-name frontend --image-ids imageTag=latest; then
            echo "Frontend image exists."
            echo "::set-output name=exists::true"
          else
            echo "Frontend image does not exist."
            echo "::set-output name=exists::false"
          fi

      - name: Build and push frontend Docker image
        if: steps.frontend-image-check.outputs.exists == 'false'
        run: |
          docker buildx build --platform linux/amd64,linux/arm64 -f ./frontend/DockerfileProd -t ${{ secrets.AWS_ACCOUNT_ID }}.dkr.ecr.${{ secrets.AWS_REGION }}.amazonaws.com/frontend:latest --push ./frontend

      - name: Install AWS CLI
        run: |
          sudo apt-get update
          sudo apt-get install -y awscli

      - name: Create CloudWatch Logs group
        run: |
          aws logs create-log-group --log-group-name /ecs/kanastra || true


      - name: Create ECS Task Definition
        run: |
          echo '{
            "family": "kanastra-task",
            "networkMode": "awsvpc",
            "containerDefinitions": [
              {
                "name": "db",
                "image": "postgres",
                "essential": true,
                "memory": 512,
                "cpu": 256,
                "environment": [
                  { "name": "POSTGRES_DB", "value": "kanastra_db" },
                  { "name": "POSTGRES_USER", "value": "kanastra_user" },
                  { "name": "POSTGRES_PASSWORD", "value": "mypassword" },
                  { "name": "POSTGRES_PORT", "value": "5432" }
                ],
                "portMappings": [
                  { "containerPort": 5432,
                    "protocol": "tcp" }
                ],
                "logConfiguration": {
                  "logDriver": "awslogs",
                  "options": {
                    "awslogs-group": "/ecs/kanastra",
                    "awslogs-region": "${{ secrets.AWS_REGION }}",
                    "awslogs-stream-prefix": "db"
                  }
                }
              },
              {
                "name": "web",
                "image": "${{ secrets.AWS_ACCOUNT_ID }}.dkr.ecr.${{ secrets.AWS_REGION }}.amazonaws.com/backend:latest",
                "essential": true,
                "memory": 512,
                "cpu": 256,
                "environment": [
                  { "name": "DB_NAME", "value": "kanastra_db" },
                  { "name": "DB_USER", "value": "kanastra_user" },
                  { "name": "DB_PASSWORD", "value": "mypassword" },
                  { "name": "DB_HOST", "value": "db" },
                  { "name": "DB_PORT", "value": "5432" }
                ],
                "portMappings": [
                  { "containerPort": 8000,
                    "protocol": "tcp" }
                ],
                "command": [
                  "sh", "-c",
                  "echo 'Waiting for DB to be ready...' && /usr/local/bin/wait-for-it.sh db:5432 -- echo 'DB is ready, starting application...' && python manage.py makemigrations && python manage.py migrate && python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000"
                ],
                "logConfiguration": {
                  "logDriver": "awslogs",
                  "options": {
                    "awslogs-group": "/ecs/kanastra",
                    "awslogs-region": "${{ secrets.AWS_REGION }}",
                    "awslogs-stream-prefix": "web"
                  }
                }
              },
              {
                "name": "frontend",
                "image": "${{ secrets.AWS_ACCOUNT_ID }}.dkr.ecr.${{ secrets.AWS_REGION }}.amazonaws.com/frontend:latest",
                "essential": true,
                "memory": 512,
                "cpu": 256,
                "portMappings": [
                  { "containerPort": 3000, "hostPort": 3000 }
                ],
                "logConfiguration": {
                  "logDriver": "awslogs",
                  "options": {
                    "awslogs-group": "/ecs/kanastra",
                    "awslogs-region": "${{ secrets.AWS_REGION }}",
                    "awslogs-stream-prefix": "frontend"
                  }
                }
              }
            ],
            "requiresCompatibilities": ["FARGATE"],
            "cpu": "1024",
            "memory": "2048",
            "executionRoleArn": "arn:aws:iam::${{ secrets.AWS_ACCOUNT_ID }}:role/ecsTaskExecutionRole"
          }' > ecs-task-def.json

      - name: Register ECS Task Definition
        run: |
          aws ecs register-task-definition \
            --cli-input-json file://ecs-task-def.json

      - name: Create or Update ECS Service
        run: |
          SERVICE_NAME=${{ secrets.ECS_SERVICE }}
          CLUSTER_NAME=${{ secrets.ECS_CLUSTER }}
          TASK_DEFINITION=kanastra-task

          while true; do
            SERVICE_STATE=$(aws ecs describe-services --cluster $CLUSTER_NAME --services $SERVICE_NAME --query 'services[0].status' --output text)
            if [ "$SERVICE_STATE" == "ACTIVE" ]; then
              echo "Service is active, updating..."
              aws ecs update-service \
                --cluster $CLUSTER_NAME \
                --service $SERVICE_NAME \
                --task-definition $TASK_DEFINITION \
                --force-new-deployment
              break
            elif [ "$SERVICE_STATE" == "INACTIVE" ] || [ "$SERVICE_STATE" == "None" ]; then
              echo "Service is inactive, creating a new service..."
              aws ecs create-service \
                --cluster $CLUSTER_NAME \
                --service-name $SERVICE_NAME \
                --task-definition $TASK_DEFINITION \
                --desired-count 1 \
                --launch-type FARGATE \
                --network-configuration "awsvpcConfiguration={subnets=[${{ secrets.AWS_SUBNET }}],securityGroups=[${{ secrets.AWS_SECURITY_GROUP }}],assignPublicIp=ENABLED}"
              break
            else
              echo "Service is in state $SERVICE_STATE, waiting for it to become active..."
              sleep 30
            fi
          done

and my wait-for-it.sh file:
#!/usr/bin/env bash
# Use this script to test if a given TCP host/port are available

TIMEOUT=60
QUIET=0
HOST="$1"
PORT="$2"

echo "Waiting for $HOST:$PORT to be available..."

for i in `seq $TIMEOUT` ; do
    echo "Attempt $i: Checking connection to $HOST:$PORT..."
    nc -zv "$HOST" "$PORT" > /dev/null 2>&1
    result=$?
    if [ $result -eq 0 ] ; then
        echo "Connection to $HOST:$PORT succeeded."
        exit 0
    fi
    echo "Attempt $i: Connection to $HOST:$PORT failed."
    sleep 1
done

echo "Operation timed out after $TIMEOUT seconds" >&2
exit 1```



I tried change the localhost from db to localhost but did not work, im expecting the container to do not stop and see this functional, remembering that im pushing images to ECR from a macbook m1, but i think i fixed this in build part and ECS service is working, and db container is good, if was something behind i think i would not have gotten so far to ECS.


You are deploying to Fargate. With Fargate, all containers running in the same task share an Elastic Network Interface, and can communicate with each other over localhost or 127.0.0.1 via their respective ports. This is documented here.
If you change this:
{ "name": "DB_HOST", "value": "db" },

to this:
{ "name": "DB_HOST", "value": "127.0.0.1" },

it should work.

Hi, @Mark B, thanks in advance, i tried it and does not work, i also deleted the part of calling wait-for-it.sh to see if it was the problem, and was not. I allowed all traffic in all ports and ip's in inbound and outbound rules inside security groups inside vpc and i get in web service log a message of connection refuse.
django.db.utils.OperationalError: connection to server at "127.0.0.1", port 5432 failed: Connection refused
Is the server running on that host and accepting TCP/IP connections?
at this point i think that it should be something very dumb that im doing.

I don't see anything else you would need to change. The security group is not involved in connections to 127.0.0.1, so that isn't an issue. Have you checked the postgres task's logs to make sure the DB is actually up and running? You might need to add a dependsOn condition in the Django container's definition, to make ECS wait for the Postgres container to start before it tries to start the Django container.

i dont need to worry about configuring traffic in ports for db contaienr and web container? i did not know that, i check my db and it shows that is ok and accepting connections, so i presumed it was all ok, but im not using docker compose anymore, as far as i learned, i translated all docker composes settings to a task definition, right? as is coded in pipeline above, im lost, ;(

I never mentioned docker compose, I'm not sure why you are bringing it up. You need to add dependsOn in your Task Definition, to tell it that Django depends on Postgres. Search for "dependsOn" here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/task_definition_parameters.html

Im sorry, i linked this because im used to this parameter in docker compose and got confused, ill try what you said and bring a result!

It does not work, i get the same message of connection refused, i tested locally with my docker compose and it is working well, i dont know anymore where to change!
now instead of wait-for-it.sh file i used a python file to test db and also got connection refused:
django.db.utils.OperationalError: connection to server at "127.0.0.1", port 5432 failed: Connection refused
